# Removing all non-digits from string

Tags: java, regex, numberformatexception

I am implementing a calculator where it is possible to type any character. However, I want to extract the numbers from what is typed and add them together.

An example of an input could be:

```
"//;\n1;2"
```

Here the the result should be 3.

What I am trying to do is to replace every non-digit in the string with empty.

```
string.replaceAll("\\D", "");
```

When I print the string afterwards, I get:

```
//;
1;2
```

When I try to add the digits together I am getting the exception:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please add your code

Comment: `"//;\\n1;2.".replaceAll("\\D", "")` returns `12`

Comment: what you mean by `When I try to add the digits together` ?

Comment: @xxxvodnikxxx: Addition. So the result should be 1+2 = 3, in my case

Answer (score 6):

Strings are immutable. Once you have a String object, its content won't ever change.

To provide you with a different String, replaceAll() returns a new String with the changes requested, as do all other similar methods. It doesn't change the content of the String, which is an impossibility.

You need to do:

```
string = string.replaceAll("\\D", "");
```

Comment: Nice! What do I have to do in order to add the numbers together. In case my it should be 1+2=3

Comment: @Bab A loop, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

For example..

> note- this will work only for numbers in interval (incl.) <0;9>

```
    String input = "//;\n1;2";

    //contains digits only
    String tmp = input.replaceAll("\\D", "");
    System.out.println("tmp is: " + tmp);

    //convert String to char array 
    char[] charsArray = tmp.toCharArray();
    int sum = 0;

    //iterate over and summarize
    for (int i = 0; i < charsArray.length; i++) {
        //needs to be there otherwise you will get crazy numbers 
        sum = sum + Character.getNumericValue(charsArray[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("sum is: " + sum);
```

Comment: How is it possible that I am able to write negative numbers, but it still gives 3? Does it also remove operators (+ and -)?

Comment: I guess so, if I am correct, then regex `String tmp = input.replaceAll("\\D", "");` will replace everything what is not a number, and in case of two-or-more digit numbers, you cant to know if '111' was 1+1+1, or 11+1 or 1+11. Reg. regex, yes `\D - Matches anything other than a decimal digit`